# Get opening hours from GMSPlace in iOS

Tags: ios, google-places-api, google-places, gmsplace

Is there a way to get opening hours for a GMPlace in iOS SDK?

I could only find `- (GMSPlacesOpenNowStatus) openNowStatus [read, assign]`
 which doesn't contain opening hours, and anyhow appears to be buggy and always return "unknown" (reference: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8160).

Looking for an iOS was to find opening hours, rather than making a `GET` request from iOS to the web API with the retrieved `placeID`.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps API only returns the following info: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_place#properties

I checked the MapKit API and it doesn't return anything like that either.

Maybe try the Google search API? I know you get that info back in some cases when doing a google.com search.
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results#overview

Comment: I am able to get this information by sending a request to the Web API, which I guess is an adequate hack for now. Was hoping there's some undocumented endpoint in the iOS SDK :(

Comment: @Kreutzer: Would you be able to provide a bit more details? How did you use the Web API to get these info?

Comment: @EdouardBarbier I was able to get such data from Web API by sending requests with Alamofire. You can check api doc here: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details Seems that iOS SDK is a bit abridged